# How do I get data from a form while the user is typing in his data? Django/Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a problem I am currently working on. Really new to django and python. What I am trying to do is I have a form where the user can rent a parking lots for a certain period of time.

I want to be able to dynamically calculate the value of the price based on the time the user selects and show this to the user. Meaning that price x time selected will generate a price that the user should be able to see.

I do have a view where the user can rent a parking lot. I tried to write a function where the price is dynamically calculated, but I can't come up with how to get the user data before the reservation form is submitted.

Below you see the view I wrote for the reservation:

```
def list_parking_lots(request):
    """
    View for all parking lots
    :param request: request from user
    :return: rendered parking_mgmt/list_parking_lots.html
    """
    parking_lots = ParkingLot.objects.all()
    form = ReservationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your reservation was successfully registered.')
            form = ReservationForm()
    return render(request, 'parking_mgmt/list_parking_lots.html', {'parking_lots': parking_lots, 'form': form})
```

OK. So thanks to you guys input I have created a simple ajax request. Now I am still not sure if I understand it Right tho. With the ajax url parameter I should be able to send the data I want to the view above, right?

This is the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#reservationModal").serialize(),
        url: "{% url 'parking_lots' %}",
        success: function(data)
        {
            //alert(data);
            $('#userError').html(data);
        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want to compute anything client-side, you would need a two-phase process here; one form you submit to calculate the price, and another to confirm the registration.

Comment: I edited the question a bit. It's not said that I need to do this in one go. So you would also recommend writing another function.
And I don't quite get what you mean when you say I should use another form to calculate the data. Please bear with me, I have a terrible headache and am not able to think very fast today.

Comment: have a look into xhr/ajax. Call a backend function via js-> xhr when your fields are selected and return backend values

Comment: Ok. Now I have have tried to send it with an ajax request. But I still don't seem to do it right.
As far as I understand it, the url should be the place where I want the data to be send, right. So I could send it to the above mentioned view. Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: yes if you are doing a post request your view should handle it. You can try to debug your problem by using a debugger or by setting print and console.log() statments. your ajax call does not have a error handling right now. under success you can add error and log the result to see whats wrong. maybe your form does not validate. Try to find the error message.